# The app manifest publisher name (CN={digits}) must match the subject name of the signing certificate (CN=anton)

Tags: uwp

error 0x8007000B: The app manifest publisher name (CN=563776A1-7D2D-4E8E-AFE2-XXXXXX) must match the subject name of the signing certificate (CN=anton).
I have searched all over the web and I get answer such as "you have to make sure that the Publisher name (in the AppxManifest.xml file) is the same as the certificate's publisher." but no explanation of how to do it. I have checked all my files and they all have the same publisher name so what is the problem?

Comment: So if you open the `Package.appxmanifest` file in your project (right-click on it and choose "View Code" in Visual Studio) and locate the `Identity` element, the value of its `Publisher` element is "CN=anton"?

Comment: @mm8 my Publisher elemnt is 563776A1-7D2D-4E8E-AFE2-XXXXXX not anton

Comment: You need to change it then. See the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, the `Publisher` (in the manifest) must match the `Subject` of the certificate used to sign your application. If you are developing in Visual Studio and just trying to run / install the app locally, you will get a temporary key with your name (like `"CN=anton"`) - just make sure the `Publisher` in the AppX manifest matches this name.

```
<Identity
  Name="NameOfTheApp"
  Publisher="CN=MustMatchWhatsInYourCertificate"
  Version="1.0.0.0" />
```

If you get the app signed by the Store, or by some other certificate for broader distribution, you need to make sure the names match. You can see the `Subject` of any certificate by running `certutil` (just press enter for the password if it's the temporary VS certificate):

```
c:\> certutil -dump ProjectName_TemporaryKey.pfx
Enter PFX password:
================ Certificate 0 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 0:
Serial Number: <blah>
Issuer: CN=Peter
 NotBefore: 12/13/2018 2:02 PM
 NotAfter: 12/13/2019 8:02 PM
Subject: CN=Peter <====================================================== Here
Signature matches Public Key
Root Certificate: Subject matches Issuer
Cert Hash(sha1): <bla>
```

Comment: I'm using WiX to generate an MSIX which contains an AppxManifiest.xml.  According to certutil my CN contains a comma.  What is the correct way to escape that in the xml?

Comment: Commas are fine in the AppXManifest file.

Answer (score 2):

The AppxManifest.xml expects Publisher Identity to match the Code Signing Certificate subject **exactly**. It is not immediately clear what the exact subject is when you look at the .cer file properties, or even when you look at your certificate subject in HSM like Azure Key Vault. It turns out that these are often incomplete and don't show all information.

You can find the full and exact subject by following these steps:

1. Install the certificate on a PC (right-click on the .cer file, and click Install)
2. Use PowerShell to find the certificate and then print its subject:

   PS> $cert = Get-Item     Cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPeople\{CERT GUID}

   PS> $cert.Subject

Note: I also had to change one of the flags from 'ST' to 'S' (for state, like California in the US or Berkshire in the UK) in the AppxManifest.xml file.

More information in this thread that really helped me: https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool/issues/119#issuecomment-867987795

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing great and helpful answers, you can get the Subject line a little bit easier, without retrieving the certificate from Azure KeyVault and installing it:

1. Sign any exe or DLL with your certificate
2. Execute this in PowerShell:

`(Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath <yourPathToSignedFile>).SignerCertificate.Subject`

That will give you the exact line to copy and paste into the manifest.